# BigQuery: return application dated immediately prior to the date a new record added

Tags: arrays, join, google-bigquery

What I'm trying to do: When a record is added in one table, I need to return the application dated prior to the date the record was added.

For example, Table 1 has cust info (name, address, date of application). Table 2 has a list of actions taken (mail received, call made, etc.). Mr. Smith has 5 applications on file dated 01.15.19, 02.15.20, 03.15.21, 04.15.22, 05.15.23. A record is entered that we received a piece of mail on 06.15.21. I need the application date of 03.15.21 returned.

I'm starting from square one here. I am comfortable with BigQuery but this is outside my wheelhouse so I'm asking the experts :) I believe I need to return an array but get lost on how to indicate which date to return.